# systemd unit file: how to depend on one service OR another service?

Tags: systemd

I'm writing a unit file that Requires= either service A or service B, but I don't care which. How can I specify this?

Comment: Just specify one or the other.

Comment: I want my unit to be able to work for people using either service.

Comment: Do you want it to be a hard/soft dependency or to just have it start after the other two?

Comment: It needs one of the services to be present to start.

Comment: Then, again, you can just `Require=oneservice.service`. It doesn't matter whether the service is being used as long as it's running.

Comment: But if I do Requires=A, wouldn't that mean it would fail on a machine where only B is installed?

Comment: Yes. You would have to alter it depending on which service was installed. `Requires` means that it's a hard dependency so it won't start or continue to run unless the required service(s) are running. `Wants` and `After` could get around this after it's running as it wouldn't stop if the dependency stopped but in order to start, it would need the depencies to stop. The best way to do it in your case is to require the service that's actually on the machine. If you are deploying an image to other machines then you'll need to make a template for each case.

Comment: I've got this exact same question. I can't believe that no one has answered this in nearly 3 years! Surely this is not a crazy strange requirement?!

Comment: I was following this question for a while now, your note also surprises me. Maybe we should file a FR at https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues. If no one answered after 3 years, it's probably not possible to do so natively.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be adding a test for A or B as `ExecStartPre`

```
[Unit]
Description=this unit needs A or B

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/systemctl is-active --quiet A || /usr/bin/systemctl is-active --quiet B'
ExecStart=/the/actual/command
```

The alternative being having the test for A or B as separate service unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=this service is active if A or B are present

[Service]
[Unit]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Description=test for A or B                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[Service]                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/systemctl is-active --quiet A || /usr/bin/systemctl is-active --quiet B'
```

Then add dependencies on `A_B_checker.service` to the main service.